# How can I scrape HTML from an open tab in chrome?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I need to access live data from a website. However, it requires a login with captcha and a chrome browser.  I tried to accomplish this using WebClient but I couldn't get around the captcha and chrome browser requirement.

So, I'd like to manually log in with a chrome browser to the exact page with the data that I need.  Then trigger an external program to access the html from the open browser tab and monitor it for new data.  My preferred language is c#

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: CefSharp. It is a .NET wrapper around CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework).

Comment: @elgonzo can you add this as an answer because I think this might really help, I'll try it out tonight

Comment: For c# you're looking for Selenium probably

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer is what you need.
A simple javascript script can load the page, wait for you to login and then scrape whatever data you need from the page.

https://pptr.dev

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.